# Using data.table to left join with equality and inequality conditions, and multiple matches per left table row

Tags: r, data.table, left-join, inequality

I am trying to determine how to join two datasets using `data.table` methods on a condition which contains both an equality and an inequality as sub-conditions. Here is some example data:

```
> A <- data.table(name = c("Sally","Joe","Fred"),age = c(20,25,30))
> B <- data.table(name = c("Sally","Joe","Fred","Fred"),age = c(20,30,35,40),condition = c("deceased","good","good","ailing"))
> A
    name age
1: Sally  20
2:   Joe  25
3:  Fred  30

> B
    name age condition
1: Sally  20  deceased
2:   Joe  30      good
3:  Fred  35      good
4:  Fred  40    ailing
```

When I execute `A[B,on =.(name = name, age < age), condition := i.condition]` I only get back the following 3 rows:

```
> A
    name age condition
1: Sally  20      <NA>
2:   Joe  25      good
3:  Fred  30    ailing
```

counter to the intuition a typical SQL user would have that all rows which match the join condition be returned (in this case there would be 4). I am using data.table_1.11.8.

Is there a `data.table` approach which will allow me to

1. Handle conditions whose sub-conditions may be a mixture of equality
   and inequality conditions
2. Assign values to an existing dataset using `:=` to avoid unnecessary memory usage
3. Keep all rows that match the join condition as SQL would

?

If there is no data.table solution, what is the best alternative (my datasets are quite large, and I'd prefer to require as few packages as possible)?

**EDIT**

To clarify what output I'm looking for I'll give the SQL code who's functionality I'm trying to emulate:

```
create table #A (
name varchar(50),
age integer
);

insert into #A
values ('Sally',20),
       ('Joe',25),
       ('Fred',30);

create table #B (
name varchar(50),
age integer,
condition varchar(50)
);

insert into #B
values ('Sally',20,'deceased'),
       ('Joe',30,'good'),
       ('Fred',35,'good'),
       ('Fred',40,'ailing');

select
#A.*,
condition
from #A left join #B
on  #A.name = #B.name
and #A.age < #B.age;
```

The above returns the following result set:

```
name    age   condition
Sally   20    NULL
Joe     25    good
Fred    30    good
Fred    30    ailing
```

Comment: You want `A[B,on =.(name = name, age < age), .(name, age, condition = i.condition)]` I think. The join code doesn't modify `A`, it creates a new data table. `A[B` is `A right join B` in SQL terms.

Comment: I see, so using this method I would need to write the result to `A`, right? I'll see if sacrificing the memory is doable for my code, I'm glad just to have a solution, but a solution which takes advantage of `data.table`'s memory saving features would be ideal. I'll need to read up on documentation to understand what your solution is doing. Feel free to post as answer for the accept, and thanks!

Comment: You can make the join by modifying `B` with something like `B[, age := A[.SD, on =.(name = name, age < age), x.age]]`, but for some reason this gives `NA` for Sally's age. I'm trying to copy one of Frank's SO answers from memory here. I'm sure he'll show up to give an answer at some point.

Comment: Maybe you're right that it's not a right join, idk. I just said that because that's what the documentation says. See pg. 4 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf "In SQL
terms, x[i] then performs a right join by default"

Comment: `A[B, on=(...)]` returns `select a.*, b.condition from A right join B on ...`. Right join rows are A inner join B rows plus unmatched B rows extended by nulls in A columns. That's B 2-4 each matched once plus B 1 extended by nulls. Then select. But adding the assignment says to update A, which has 3 rows, using the right join. But for A rows that had no match, assignment uses NAs for join (`x.`,  `i.` & B-only) columns. Hence the NA condition for A 1 in the updated value of A that your code produces. PS What were you trying to do, in SQL terms? What do you expect this to output & why? [mcve]

Comment: @RyanD `A[B` is A right join B, but the assignment means that instead of the join being returned as a result it is used to update A & unmatched left table rows get NAs from the right join. See my last comment.

Comment: Yeah, I think desired output is needed to clarify how you expect "assign" and "return" to both be involved here. Data.tables/data.frames have a fixed number of rows that is preserved under assignment to columns.

Comment: I see. If the row count is fixed with assignment, that seems to rule out the everything I'm asking for here. I've updated the post to include desired output. Thanks all for the attention to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a SQL style left join (as detailed in the edit) is desired, this can be achieved using a  code quite similar to [icecreamtoucan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6762755/icecreamtoucan)'s suggestion in the comments:

```
B[A,on=.(name = name, age > age)]
```

Note: if the result set exceeds the sum of the row counts of the elements of the join, `data.table` will assume you've made a mistake (unlike SQL engines) and throw an error. The solution (assuming you *have not* made an error) is to add `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

Additionally, and unlike SQL, this join does not return all columns from the constituent tables. Instead (and somewhat frustratingly for those coming from a SQL background) column values from the left table used in the inequality condition of the join will be returned in ***columns with the names of the right table column*** compared to it in the inequality join condition!

The solution here (which I found some time ago in another SO answer but can't find now) is to create duplicates of the join columns you want to keep, use those for the join conditions then specify the columns to keep in the join.

e.g.

```
A <- data.table( group = rep("WIZARD LEAGUE",3)
                ,name = rep("Fred",time=3)
                ,status_start = as.Date("2017-01-01") + c(0,370,545)
                ,status_end = as.Date("2017-01-01") + c(369,544,365*3-1) 
                ,status = c("UNEMPLOYED","EMPLOYED","RETIRED"))
A <- rbind(A, data.table( group = "WIZARD LEAGUE"
                         ,name = "Sally"
                         ,status_start = as.Date("2017-01-01")
                         ,status_end = as.Date("2019-12-31")
                         ,status = "CONTRACTED"))
> A
           group  name status_start status_end     status
1: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2017-01-01 2018-01-05 UNEMPLOYED
2: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-01-06 2018-06-29   EMPLOYED
3: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-06-30 2019-12-31    RETIRED
4: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED


B <- data.table( group = rep("WIZARD LEAGUE",time=5)
                ,loc_start = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 180*0:4
                ,loc_end = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 180*1:5-1
                , loc = c("US","GER","FRA","ITA","MOR"))

> B
           group  loc_start    loc_end loc
1: WIZARD LEAGUE 2017-01-01 2017-06-29  US
2: WIZARD LEAGUE 2017-06-30 2017-12-26 GER
3: WIZARD LEAGUE 2017-12-27 2018-06-24 FRA
4: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-06-25 2018-12-21 ITA
5: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-12-22 2019-06-19 MOR

>#Try to join all rows whose date ranges intersect:

>B[A,on=.(group = group, loc_end >= status_start,  loc_start <= status_end)]
```

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||
>   !anyDuplicated(f__,  :    Join results in 12 rows; more than 9 =
>   nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which
>   join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try
>   by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If
>   you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE.
>   Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki,
>   Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

```
>#Try the join with allow.cartesian = TRUE
>#this succeeds but messes up column names

> B[A,on=.(group = group, loc_end >= status_start,  loc_start <= status_end), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
            group  loc_start    loc_end loc  name     status
 1: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-01-05 2017-01-01  US  Fred UNEMPLOYED
 2: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-01-05 2017-01-01 GER  Fred UNEMPLOYED
 3: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-01-05 2017-01-01 FRA  Fred UNEMPLOYED
 4: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-06-29 2018-01-06 FRA  Fred   EMPLOYED
 5: WIZARD LEAGUE 2018-06-29 2018-01-06 ITA  Fred   EMPLOYED
 6: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2018-06-30 ITA  Fred    RETIRED
 7: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2018-06-30 MOR  Fred    RETIRED
 8: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2017-01-01  US Sally CONTRACTED
 9: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2017-01-01 GER Sally CONTRACTED
10: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2017-01-01 FRA Sally CONTRACTED
11: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2017-01-01 ITA Sally CONTRACTED
12: WIZARD LEAGUE 2019-12-31 2017-01-01 MOR Sally CONTRACTED

>#Create aliased duplicates of the columns in the inequality condition
>#and specify the columns to keep

> keep_cols <- c(names(A),setdiff(names(B),names(A)))
> A[,start_dup := status_start]
> A[,end_dup := status_end]
> B[,start := loc_start]
> B[,end := loc_end]
>
>#Now the join works as expected (by SQL convention)
>
> B[ A
    ,..keep_cols
    ,on=.( group = group
          ,end >= start_dup
          ,start <= end_dup)
          ,allow.cartesian = TRUE]
            group  name status_start status_end     status  loc_start    loc_end loc
 1: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2017-01-01 2018-01-05 UNEMPLOYED 2017-01-01 2017-06-29  US
 2: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2017-01-01 2018-01-05 UNEMPLOYED 2017-06-30 2017-12-26 GER
 3: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2017-01-01 2018-01-05 UNEMPLOYED 2017-12-27 2018-06-24 FRA
 4: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-01-06 2018-06-29   EMPLOYED 2017-12-27 2018-06-24 FRA
 5: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-01-06 2018-06-29   EMPLOYED 2018-06-25 2018-12-21 ITA
 6: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-06-30 2019-12-31    RETIRED 2018-06-25 2018-12-21 ITA
 7: WIZARD LEAGUE  Fred   2018-06-30 2019-12-31    RETIRED 2018-12-22 2019-06-19 MOR
 8: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED 2017-01-01 2017-06-29  US
 9: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED 2017-06-30 2017-12-26 GER
10: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED 2017-12-27 2018-06-24 FRA
11: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED 2018-06-25 2018-12-21 ITA
12: WIZARD LEAGUE Sally   2017-01-01 2019-12-31 CONTRACTED 2018-12-22 2019-06-19 MOR
```

I'm certainly not the first person to point out these departures from SQL convention, or that it is rather cumbersome to reproduce that functionality (as seen above), and I do believe [improvements are actively being considered](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2006).

To anyone contemplating alternative strategies (e.g. the `sqldf` package) I will say that while there are meritorious alternatives to to `data.table`, I have struggled to find any solution that compares with the speed of `data.table` when very large datasets are involved, both with respect to joins as well as other operations. Needless to say there are many other benefits that make this package indispensable to me and many others. So for those working with large datasets I would advise against abandoning `data.table` joins if the above looks cumbersome and instead either get in the habit of going through these motions or else write a helper function that replicates the sequence of actions until an improvement to the syntax comes along.

Finally, I did not mention disjunctive joins here, but as far as I can tell this is another shortcoming of the `data.table` approach (and another area where `sqldf` is helpful). I have been getting around these with ad-hoc "hacks" of a sort, but I would appreciate any helpful advice on the best way to treat these in `data.table`.